# Authenticate users with SpringSecurity using a WebService that requires a username and password

Tags: java, web-services, spring-security

Currently I am writing a web application using Spring Security. We have a web service which authenticates users by username and password.

**Web service:**

`String[] login(String username, String password);`

How do I configure Spring Security to pass the provided username and password to the web service?

I have written a `UserDetailsService` which only receives a username.

---

I think the problem is with your xml. Did you turned off the auto-config? And does your class extend AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extend org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider

```
/**
 * @author rodrigoap
 * 
 */
public class WebServiceUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider extends
    AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
     //Improve this line:
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    // Invoke your webservice here
    GrantedAuthority[] grantedAuth = loginWebService.login(username, password);
    // create UserDetails. Warning: User is deprecated!
    UserDetails userDetails = new User(username, password, grantedAuth);
    return userDetails;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have written to following class:

`PncUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`

Which implements the recieveUser methode:

```
@Override
protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        server = (PncUtilRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("PncUtilBean");
        if (server != null) {
            String password = SHA1(token.getCredentials().toString());
            String[] auth = server.login(username, password);
            if (auth.length > 0) {
                PncUserDetails details = new PncUserDetails(username, password);
                for (int i = 0; i < auth.length; i++) {
                    details.addAuthority(auth[i]);
                }
                return details;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("! " + e.getClass().getName() + " in com.logica.pnc.security.PncUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(String, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken): " + e.getMessage());
    }
    throw new BadCredentialsException("");
}
```

To enable your AuthenticationProvider you need to add some lines to your application-context.xml file:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list><ref local="PncAuthenticationProvider" /></list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="PncAuthenticationProvider" class="com.logica.pnc.security.PncUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider">
    <security:custom-authentication-provider />
</bean>
```

It is important that you set the auto-config to false:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" />
```

Thanks to rodrigoap for pointing to the AuthenticationProvider thingy :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea with UserDetailsService is that your implementation provides a UserDetails object representing the user with that username, and Spring Security handles checking the credentials.

If that kind of design doesn't work well with your backend, because you require the password as a parameter, then you might need to look at implementing your own AuthenticationProvider.